# Fast API get_current_user as a service method

Tags: fastapi, fastapiusers

I have service ( UserService) where i store all functionality connected to user. How can I use service method like `async def get_current_user` as a dependency, in my router function?

```
from typing import Annotated

from passlib.context import CryptContext

from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer

from src.auth.schemas import UserInDTO
from src.auth.models import User
from src.auth.messages import errors
from src.auth.services.token_service import TokenService
from src.auth.repositories.user_repository import UserRepository


pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="users/token")


class UserService:
    def __init__(self, repository: UserRepository = Depends()) -> None:
        self.repository = repository

    async def register_user(self, user: UserInDTO) -> User:
        if await self.get_user_by_email(email=user.email):
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                detail=errors.USER_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS
            )

        user.hashed_password = self.hash_password(user.hashed_password)

        return await self.repository.create(User(**user.model_dump()))

    async def get_current_user(
            self,
            token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)],
            token_service: TokenService = Depends(),
    ) -> User:
        token_data = token_service.verify_token(token=token)
        email = token_data.email
        user = await self.get_user_by_email(email=email)

        if not email or not user:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Could not validate credentials",
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )

        return user

    async def authenticate_user(self, email: str, password: str) -> User | HTTPException:
        user = await self.get_user_by_email(email=email)

        if not user or not self.verify_password(plain_password=password, hashed_password=user.hashed_password):
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail=errors.USER_INCORECT_CREDENTIALS,
                headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
            )
        return user

    async def get_user_by_email(self, email: str) -> User:
        return await self.repository.get(identifier=email)

    def verify_password(self, plain_password: str, hashed_password: str) -> bool:
        return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

    def hash_password(self, plain_password: str) -> str:
        return pwd_context.hash(plain_password)
```

I try create specific file for dependencies where i put something like this:

```
def get_current_user(user_service: UserService = Depends()) -> User:
    return user_service.get_current_user
```

and then in my router function

```
@router.get("me/")
def test_me(user: Annotated\[UserOutDTO, Depends(get_current_user)\]):
    return user
```

Result:

```
{'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response',), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': \<bound method UserService.get_current_user of \<src.auth.services.user_ser
vice.UserService object at 0x7f2ddd603ed0\>\>, 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/model_attributes_type'}
```

Comment: You should _call the method_, just not return it: `return user_service.get_current_user()`. However, I'd try to keep any `Depends` away from the service; those should be on your `get_current_user` function as they will not be resolved on regular function/method calls from inside your code (and would make your `UserService` independent of FastAPI and then reusable across projects and frameworks).

Comment: @MatsLindh I tried this option, but then the framework complains that I don't pass the token itself when the token is a dependency in my get_current_user method.

Comment: @MatsLindh right now i have something like this: user: Annotated[UserOutDTO, Depends(UserService().get_current_user)], and it works, I successfully authenticate, but then I get an error AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: That error is caused by depends only being resolved when it's part of the dependency hierarchy, you're calling a function with  `Depends` without it being resolved as part of a controller's signature (i.e. with a regular function call). Having `token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme))` as part of your `get_current_user`  function should work fine, you then pass that into `UserService` - but you'll also need to create TokenService when creating your UserService (i.e. in the dependency and then pass it to the constructor) or create it when necessary in code and not in the signature.